# Как в Google Tag Manager собрать статистику поисковых запросов?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Вопрос чуть сложнее, чем кажется на первый взгляд. Необходимо не просто собрать статистику поисковых запросов на сайте, но и дальнейшее поведение пользователя. Например:
"Поисковый запрос пользователя" -> "URL страницы из поисковой выдачи, по которой далее перешел пользователь".
Спасибо.